# Search for all matching values in one column and if adjacent column contains "X" return "Y"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large data set that contains a column with an ID then sub ID's and then status of the sub ID.  FYI; a sub ID can have two statuses.  I would like a formula to look in Column A and find all matching values and if the status of any equals "x" then return a defined value.

Example:

```
A        B      C
1-001   0550    UD
1-001   0550    DV
1-001   0003    UD
1-001   0001    UD
1-001   1   
1-003   0550    UD
1-003   0003    UD
1-003   0001    UD
1-003   1   
1-005   0550    UD
1-005   0550    DV
1-005   0027    UD
1-005   0026    UD
1-005   0024    UD
1-005   0023    UD
1-005   0017    UD
1-005   0014    UD
1-005   0012    UD
1-005   0011    UD
1-005   0003    UD
1-005   0001    UD
1-005   1
```

I've tried

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7390, SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A9,$A$2:$A$7697)),MATCH(ROW($A$2:$A$7697),ROW($A$2:$A$7697))),ROW(A8))),"")
```

but that's not really what I need.....

Comment: So if a status equals "x" (which I'm guessing would actually be UD or DV) then return a "defined value".  What is the defined value?  And it sounds like [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @nbayly Thank you both for your input.  I don’t think I was clear in my initial post.  I edited the example as well to show the differences I am hoping to achieve.  The ultimate goal here is to find all ID’s that have a “DV” status and if so I want column D to read “HBP” if it does not, then I would like it to be blank.  So in this example D1:D5 would read HBP and D6:D9 would be blank.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Countifs will do the trick.  In cell D1 use this formula and copy down:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,C:C,"DV")>0,"HBP","")
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using array formula and a simple conditional. Formula would look like following assuming that ID's are in column A, Statuses on column B and looking specifically for "1-005":

```
=OR(IF(A:A="1-005",C:C,"")="DV")
```

This is inputted as an array formula pressing `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`. The if compares every cell to the search term and outputs its corresponding status in column C or an empty string in the form of an array. Then comparing that array to the Defined Value will output an array of booleans that we join in an OR that gives us TRUE if at least one of the statuses is equal to the define value. Hope this makes sense. Cheers.